# jsp select option dynamically from a database

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have table called `students` in mysql database in which class, student name,...etc., exists.

I want to use select options in jsp such that if and only if class is selected first, immediately after selecting class, all the student names of that particular class should be displayed in another select drop down automatically(dynamically) by retrieving the records from the database.

Here I want to use servlet for database connection and access all the database records through jsp by `getAttribute()`

```
<select>class
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   .....
</select> 
<select>Student
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   .....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call to retrieve data when you change "class" combobox (pass your class name from 1st combobox) and populate your 2nd Student combobox with returned data.